# Finding both count and percentage for event and non-events using unstack

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(100)
from feature_engine.encoding import OrdinalEncoder


df = pd.DataFrame({'grade': np.random.choice(list('ABCD'),size=(20)),
                   'dash': np.random.choice(list('PQRS'),size=(20)),
                   'dumeel': np.random.choice(list('QWER'),size=(20)),
                   'dumma': np.random.choice((1234),size=(20)),
                   'target': np.random.choice([0,1],size=(20))
})
```

I would like to do the below

a) event rate - Compute the % occurrence of 1s (from target column) for each unique value in a each of the input categorical column

b) non event rate - Compute the % occurrence of 0s (from target column) for each unique value in each of the input categorical columns

c) no of events - Compute the number of records of 1's (from target column) for each unique value in each of the input categorical column

d) no of non events - Compute the number of records of 0's (from target column) for each unique value in each of the input categorical column

With the help of Shubham, am able to compute the % using the below code

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('object')
df_out = (
    df.melt('target', cols)
      .groupby(['variable', 'target'])['value']
      .value_counts(normalize=True)
      .unstack(1, fill_value=0)
)
```

But now, along with the %, I would also like to get the count or no of records for each unique value in the categorical value

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach:

- Select the catgorical columns (`cols`)
- `Melt` the dataframe with `target` as id variable and `cols` as value variables
- Create frequency table (`counts`) using `groupby` + `value_counts`
- Normalize the `counts` table along the columns axis to create (`counts_norm`)
- Concat `counts` and `counts_norm`
- Reshape the dataframe using stack, unstack

```py
cols = df.select_dtypes('object')
counts = (
    df.melt('target', cols)
      .groupby(['variable', 'target'])['value']
      .value_counts().unstack()
)
counts_norm = counts.div(counts.sum(1), axis=0)
df_out = pd.concat([counts, counts_norm], keys=['N', '%_N'])\
                      .stack().unstack([0, 2], fill_value=0)
```

---

```
print(df_out)
                  N       %_N     
target            0    1    0    1
variable value                    
dash     P      4.0  3.0  0.4  0.3
         Q      2.0  3.0  0.2  0.3
         R      2.0  1.0  0.2  0.1
         S      2.0  3.0  0.2  0.3
dumeel   E      2.0  2.0  0.2  0.2
         Q      1.0  0.0  0.1  0.0
         R      4.0  6.0  0.4  0.6
         W      3.0  2.0  0.3  0.2
grade    A      4.0  2.0  0.4  0.2
         B      0.0  2.0  0.0  0.2
         C      4.0  3.0  0.4  0.3
         D      2.0  3.0  0.2  0.3
```

Comment: @TheGreat Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I've got a **working example** for you. After trying to use the [aggregate method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html), I've realised that it's the easiest to just do it this way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'grade': np.random.choice(list('ABCD'), size=(20)),
    'dash': np.random.choice(list('PQRS'), size=(20)),
    'dumeel': np.random.choice(list('QWER'), size=(20)),
    'dumma': np.random.choice((1234), size=(20)),
    'target': np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(20))
})

cols = df.select_dtypes('object')
df_out = df.melt('target', cols)

df_out.target = pd.Categorical(df_out.target, [0, 1])  # This must be made sure
df_out.value = pd.Categorical(df_out.value, list('ABCDPQRSWE'))  # This must be made sure

df_out = pd.concat(
   [df_out.groupby(['variable', 'target']).value_counts(normalize=flag).unstack('target') 
   for flag in [True, False]], axis=1, keys=['%-event', '#-event'])
```

As I've commeted in the code, it's necessary for this to work, that the appropriate columns are categorical.

You might want to rename the column MultiIndex afterwards

```
df_out.columns = ['%-no_event', '%-event', '#-no_event', '#-event']
```

Be careful with the order though!

#### The Result

[image: | variable | value | %-no_event | %-event | #-no_event | #-event | --- | ---| --- | --- | --- | ---|]